# Is there any better approach in designing this database?

Tags: database-design

CUSTOMER:

- CustomerID (PK)
- Name
- Email

PAYMENT:

- PaymentID (PK)
- Amount
- Date

PRODUCT:

- ProductID (PK)
- Type
- Name
- Price

PURCHASE:

- CustomerID (FK)
- PaymentID (FK)
- ProductID (FK)
- Quantity

Or should I move CustomerID in PURCHASE to PAYMENT or else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it were me, I would make two changes:

1) Create a "PurchaseID" field on the "Purchase" table (which can double as an order number for your customers to reference).

2) Move "Quantity" to a new table called "Purchase_Line" for each line (item) on the order (purchase).  Otherwise, you're going to repeat the CustomerID and PaymentID for each ProductID included on every order.  This way your customers can order as many products as they want, but their order only appears in the "Purchase" table once.

Otherwise, I think your normalization looks very complete.

Comment: Well you suggest I shoudl have 
PURCHASE: PurchaseID, PaymentID, ProductID?
PURCHASE_LINE: PurchaseID, Quantity?

Comment: Well I managed to move ClientID from PURCHASE to PAYMENT table by the way. Then only 2 FKs left in PURCHASE: PaymentID and ProductID

Comment: I work on an e-commerce system and this is (kind of) how we've designed our database as well. Seems like The Right Way(tm) of doing it. +1

Comment: Why would you create a surrogate key (purchaseID) when you have a sufficient natural key (all 3 foreign key references on the table)???

Comment: @Shark- From a data modeling perspective you are correct in that the key could be a composite of all 3 FK's.  But when problems happen, which would you rather have your customer reading back to you over the phone?  A 24-digit number made up of three 8-digit numbers?  Or single 8 digit number?  That's why (I feel) a surrogate key makes sense here.

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 - Thank you for the idea of PurchaseID, I had thought of that but not in the way of using as customer reference number. Merry Christmas.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to use the key as a verbal reference then yes, I agree with you. But I had assumed that it would just be a unique identifier for the data.